# Is lightning data service just for the record detail page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is Lightning data Service just for components that can be used in record detail page or can they be used in communities as well to create/view records by passing the recordsId somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer it precisely ,lightning data service cannot be used currently inside community builder or lightning out via visualforce .The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) clearly state this limitation and only Salesforce 1 and lightning container are supported .

There is no limitations on lightning page it can be used .So you can use it anywhere not just record detail page. It can be used on home page layout , Lightning tab ,quick actions and in other places in lightning experience where Salesforce allows Lightning components .

Comment: Very Nice answer @Mohith. Precise and to the point.

Comment: Indeed! Please link the doc in your post ;)

Comment: In mobile and hence will link it soon